# How to deal with complicated Size System

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, configurable-product, product-attribute

i am buiding up a sneaker Store.
Sneakers are an international Product an every Shoe comes, obviously, in different sizes. In different Parts of the world, different Sizings are used (Europe 37-46, US 5-13, UK 5-13, Asia CM 22-35).

I want to have an configurable Product where the Customer can choose the size in different systems but in BackEnd i want to have

- SimpleShoe in Size EU40/US8/UK7
- SimpleShoe in Size EU41/US8.5/UK7.5
- …

Each Shoe as one Product to handle the inventory.

Did anyone realized something like this?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

simple sku with custom options. on custom options level you can enter the simple sku for the option (1 sku = 3 country specific formats of same size)

3 different store views for country specific sizes in frontend:

```
store view eu
store view us
store view uk
```

custom option description differs per store view, e.g.

```
store view eu->custom options description (per store view) "EU 40"->sku sneaker_abc_eu40_us8_uk7
store view us->custom options description (per store view) "US 8"->sku sneaker_abc_eu40_us8_uk7
```

Kozure

Comment: Sorry i diddnt wrote that Detail down. Storeviews are not an option. I need the customer to be able to choose from a Size System they want. Like this one [here](https://en-ae.namshi.com/buy-boxfresh-cowl-sneakers-for-men-sneakers-163840.html)